# What monitor features are good for my eyes?

Tags: display, ergonomics, eye-strain

I am looking for monitors that are good on my eyes. What is most important: high resolution, large screen size, or high refresh rate? Or something else?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen. OP is not asking for hardware recommendation, but what features to look for to reduce eye strain. That's a valid question.

Comment: Most of the metrics you named are connected in some way. It also depends on what your needs are. Reading a single line of text from a display (TV) in your living room (so you're across the room) is going to be very different from reading multiple pages of a legal document while only inches away. Your current eyesight and anomalies are also going to be important. Light levels, type of work and more are important. See e.g. [this EIZO guide](https://www.eizoglobal.com/library/basics/10_ways_to_address_eye_fatigue/).

Answer (score 1):

No monitor features are "good for your eyes"; monitors are basically bad for your eyes.  What's good for your eyes is to spend less time looking at a monitor, and follow healthy practices, like taking frequent breaks, using some form of blue light reduction, etc.  In that sense, the most important monitor feature for your eyes is the off button.  :-)  At best, monitor characteristics can only make it "less bad".  Here are some considerations and context:

- High refresh rate is probably irrelevant as far as being good for your eyes.  Any potential benefit is tied to the content.  If video is created at high frame rates, a high refresh rate may provide sharper motion.  Some people see it and some don't.  That would be more of a "quality" assessment you would need to make for yourself if you use the monitor for high frame rate videos or games.  See discussion here: https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/do-you-need-a-120hz-or-240-hz-monitor/.
- Screen size and resolution aren't completely independent considerations.  The screen size and resolution, together, define how much screen real estate there is (total number of pixels), to display content.
- A large screen could potentially introduce eye fatigue just because of its size and viewing position.  There is a field of view within which it's easy to see everything on the screen.  Outside of that, your eyes need to work much harder.  The screen needs to be at an appropriate distance and height to avoid fatiguing your eyes.

  A very large screen needs to be farther away to accomplish that, and your work area may limit your ability to do that.  For screens with the same total pixels, a larger screen may need to be optimally viewed from farther away, so the size isn't really buying you anything over a smaller screen viewed closer.  This earlier question contains answers that address that: [What's the correct monitor height for large monitors?](https://superuser.com/q/231377/364367).
- The screen's pixels per inch (resolution), dictates the approximate ideal distance range, and how big the content will be in your field of view at that distance.  Your eyes can see detail down to a certain size as represented by an angle in your field of view (how big it is on your retina; the farther away the screen is, the bigger the detail that will be the same size on your retina).  A screen with very high pixels per inch may need to be relatively close for you to distinguish the detail.  A screen with low pixels per inch will need to be farther away so you don't notice the pixels, themselves.

  The sharpest screen image will be when you display content at its native resolution and at the monitor's native resolution.  So strategies like getting a high-resolution monitor and then using screen zooming to display lower-resolution content on it will not be as sharp.

  These issues are covered pretty well in several earlier threads: [Aging eyes, screen size and resolution](https://superuser.com/q/846261/364367), and [Will the pixel density difference be visible between 4K and 2K monitors at 27" size?](https://superuser.com/q/990799/364367).
- Beyond that, monitor characteristics like contrast ratio, and how you set it, like how bright it is in relation to room lighting and use of blue light filtering, affect how tiring it will be on your eyes.  External characteristics, like room lighting and reflections on the screen will make a difference.

All of these factors need to take your own vision into account.  Even with glasses to correct your vision, perfect correction may not be possible.  Your vision changes, your eyes behave differently when they're tired, your eyes' ability to deal with a monitor degrade with age, etc.  What factors are important also depends on what you use the computer for.  So what features are good for you is hard to address definitively within the scope of an answer.

The best way to buy a monitor (final selection after research) is to compare them side-by-side in the store and see which one you find easiest on your eyes.  If you can, bring your own content on a thumb drive.  But be aware that the monitors will probably look different in store lighting than at home.  Also, check that they are at their default settings for comparison, as stores sometimes tweak settings to make inexpensive monitors look bad and optimize the one they're pushing.